# Selecting specific text from element

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have element that looks like this:

```
<div class="unique class">
    <i class="generic class">text1</i>
    text2
</div>
```

Is there a good way to select text2 only? I may add that text2 always starts with "Following".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible XPath :

```
//div[@class='unique class']/text()[starts-with(normalize-space(),'Following')]
```

brief explanation :

- `//div[@class='unique class']` : find the outer `div` by its class
- `/text()[starts-with(normalize-space(),'Following')]` : find text node that is direct child of the previously found `div`, where, after normalizing spaces, starts with text "Following".

Another alternative which doesn't consider target text node's content would be :

```
//div[@class='unique class']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

The last bit (`/text()[normalize-space()]`) returns *non-empty* text nodes, that is direct child of the outer `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `text()` on the parent `div`

```
//div[@class='unique class']/text()[2]
```